# zend db query fetching undesirable columns

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

so I have this code:

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($params);
$sql = $db->select()->from(array("r" => "recc"), array("r_id" => "refID"))->joinLeft(array("c" => "comment"), "r.refID = c.refID");
$results = $db->fetchAll($sql);
print_r($results);
```

which is supposed to translate to this query:

```
SELECT refID AS r_id FROM recc r LEFT JOIN comment c ON r.refID = c.refID
```

which is supposed to only return a single column r_id and it indeed returned that single column when executed with mysql query browser

but then when you execute it with db select and print_r the results, in addition to r_id it also returned a whole bunch of fields in table comment which are populated with empty data...

did I do something wrong? how do I get the thing to only return the single column as planned...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the joinLeft(). You may need to pass an empty array() as a third parameter.

```
$sql = $db->select()
    ->from(array("r" => "recc"), array("r_id" => "refID"))
    ->joinLeft(array("c" => "comment"), "r.refID = c.refID", array());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try 
    print_r($results->toArray()); //Pure array format of result
    array('')  //    If you dont want columns from a joining table you pass as the last parameter to the join    
 array('*') //IF you want all the fields
```